# Regex match "or" set of terms "and" specific term

Tags: regex

I have a set of "or" phrases I'd like to match as well as a single term that should be included.

**Or Phrases**

Phrases with any of the following words:

- contact|demo|webinar|content

**AND w/ this exact word:**

- account

So it would match:

- contact account
- demo account
- account webinar
- content account, etc...

But not...

- demo
- account
- demo contact
- account account
- demo demo

This seems to work partially...

```
\b(contact|demo|webinar|content).*?(\b(?!\1)(account)\b)
```

But what it doesn't match (and should) is:

- account demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b(?=.*?\b(?:contact|demo|webinar|content)\b)(?=.*?\baccount\b).*
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tW6oR9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
\b(contact\b|demo\b|webinar\b|content\b)(?:(?!\1).)*(?: account)\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tW6oR9/2)